# including specific header files with same names in different directories

Tags: makefile

Here is a sample of my directory structure:

```
TopDir
|-Makefile
|-Dir1
   |- A.c
   |- A.h
   |- Config.h
|-Dir2
   |- B.c
   |- B.h
   |- Config.h
```

This is my straight forward code (Every sub directory follows the same pattern):

```
In file Config.h
# SomeConfig

in file A.h
#include "Config.h"

in file A.c
#include "A.h"
```

And here is my Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
INC_DIR = -IDir1 \
          -IDir2
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic $(INC_DIR)
AExe: A.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $
BExe: A.c B.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $
```

When I compile, i just call:

```
$make AExe
```

or

```
$make BExe
```

My problem here is I am unable to include/build a Config specific to its own directory because of -I rule which just blindly picks the first Config.h it finds. AExe builds fine including its own Config. However BExe first finds the Config.h in Dir1 and ignores the Config.h in Dir2. If i reverse the INC_DIR order to include Dir2 first then B.h gets the right Config. In my case I have more directories with similar structure and they all could have dependencies on other directories header files only. Configs are meant for the specific directory. How do I instruct in Makefile to tell A.h to make using its own Config.h and B.h to use its own Config.h.

Comment: Your makefile seems to be missing a character or two, but `BExe` seems to be made of `A.c` and `B.c`. Was that intentional? If so, it makes the solution more complicated.

Comment: $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ - This is how it should have been if that is the missing character you are referring to. Yes, BExe is made of A.c and B.c and like I said, its just a sample. BExe could have more sources from other directories.

Comment: You may be interested in this heated exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/407056/the-case-against-path-expressions-in-include-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where something like

```
#include "Dir1/Config.h"
```

might make sense. But if you want to keep the source files (including headers) as they are, we must adjust the makefile.

`BExe` is made of `A.c` and `B.c`. We can see that `A.c` includes one `Config.h`, and presumably `B.c` includes the other, so we will have two `#include "Config.h"` statements that refer to different files, so we cannot process them with one command and hope to keep them straight. We must compile them separately and then link the object files:

```
A.o: A.c
    ...

B.o: B.c
    ...

AExe: A.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

BExe: A.o B.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Now for the `...`. You must tell Make how to find the source files `A.c` and `B.c`, but once you do, it will search for included files (such as `Config.h`) in the directory of the source file that includes them. So it will use `Dir1/Config.h` when compiling `Dir/A.c`, and `Dir2/Config.h` when compiling `Dir2/B.c`.

The only thing left is to tell Make where to find `A.c` and `B.c`. You can do this explicitly:

```
A.o: Dir1/A.c
    ...

B.o: Dir2/B.c
    ...
```

or use something like [the `vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
vpath %.c Dir1 Dir2

A.o: A.c
    ...

B.o: B.c
    ...
```

Comment: I am hitting different errors with different combinations of path with you suggestion. Sometimes I end up with A.c not found or A.h not found and so with B's. Havent really nailed down the solution but I think this is the way to go. Thank you @Beta.

Answer (score 0):

One solutions is to change:

```
INC_DIR=-I$(CURDIR)
```

And then if you need to include a header from another directory do:

```
#include <AnotherDir/Header.h>
```

To include a header from the same directory do:

```
#include "Header.h"
```

It looks for `Header.h` in the same directory first.

---

So that if:

```
// Dir1/A.h
#include "Config.h"
```

and then:

```
// Dir2/B.h
#include <Dir1/A.h>
```

`B.h` includes `<Dir1/A.h>` and `<Dir1/Config.h>` as expected.

Comment: Can do this because I cant change the includes, but its a good solution and I have been thinking around it.